# How can I access the Eclipse path of the file so that I can write over the txt file?

Tags: java, path

I have txt files for 2-D game development, so that I can pull the information and write the maps.
The txt files are located under **maps** source folder.

However, when I write this code, it gives me error as
**java.io.FileNotFoundException:\maps\studentcenter.txt (System cant find the path)**//
I translated it, my IDE isnt English.

Here is the code I tried;

```
        FileWriter map = new FileWriter("/maps/studentcenter.txt");
        BufferedWriter writer =  new BufferedWriter(map) ;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++ ) {
                if (j != 23) writer.write(0 + " ");
                else writer.write(0);
                
                
            }
            System.getProperty("line.seperator");
        }
        
        writer.close();
```

Eventually what I want is that, the txt file in the Eclipse is changed as desired: **14 rows and 24 columns of 0**

Comment: The path that you used is telling the runtime that it's off the root of the file system. You'd be better off using a dedicated directory under your home directory to read and write the maps files

Comment: I am using Windows.

Comment: See edit - no differece

Comment: Well, I did not understand exactly. Can you check my work? https://ibb.co/3csRRbv

Comment: Proper Java applications are packaged and deployed as jar files. There is no knowing where that jar file will end up. You cannot use relative paths as as the current directory is arbitrary. Use a dedicated writable directory for your maps files. That should be off the user home directory